# Fullcalendar : how to get static event and moved event one time on final drop, in case of overlap?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am working on fullcalendar events and need to show a confirmation box based on some condition once on UI, when events overlap.

The action performed in this popup will decided whether to overlap an event or not.

Issue is, eventOverlap callback is called several times, even when the dragged event is hover over the other event, generating numerous calls.

Is there any way to get both static and moved event only once?

```
this.calenderOptions = {
  contentHeight: 300,
  plugins: [resourceTimelinePlugin, interaction],
  editable: true,
  header: {
    left: "prev,next",
    center: "title",
    right: "prev"
  },
  resources: this.resources,
  defaultView: "resourceTimelineDay",
  timeZone: "local",
  droppable: true,
  eventReceive: info => {
    const ref = this.dialogService.open(ConfirmationPopup, {
      header: "Confirm Action",
      width: "20%",
      contentStyle: { "max-height": "600px", overflow: "auto" }
    });
    ref.onClose.subscribe(data => {
      if (data === "no") {
        info.event.remove();
      } else if (data === "yes") {
        this.row_id = info.draggedEl.getAttribute("row-id");
        return true;
      } else {
        info.event.remove();
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
  eventOverlap: (stillEvent, movingEvent) => {
    // need to open a popover here only once.
    console.log("eventOverlap");
    return true
  },
  eventDrop : info => {
    if(info['newResource'] && info['oldResource']){
      if(info['newResource']['id'] != info['oldResource']['id']){
        info.revert();
      }
    }
    console.log("eventDrop")
  },
  eventClick : info => {
    console.log(info);
  },
  drop:info => {
    console.log("drop");
  },
  slotLabelFormat: {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    meridiem: false,
    hour12: false
  }
};

new ThirdPartyDraggable(gridEL, {
  itemSelector: ".ag-row",
  eventData: eventEl => {
    let rowId = eventEl.getAttribute("row-id");
    let data = this.commonService.grid_service.getRowNode(rowId);
    let color = null;
    if(data.data["status"] == 1){
      color = "#DEC181";
    }
    else if (data.data["status"] == 2){
      color = "#A56124";
    }
    else {
      color = "#000000";
    }
    return {
      title: data.data["shipmentId"],
      duration: data.data["est"],
      color : color,
      className: "test",
      extendedProps: [
        {
          est: data.data["est"],
          shipmentId: data.data["shipmentId"]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
});

this.calendar = new Calendar(
  this.calenderComponent.element.nativeElement,
  this.calenderOptions
);

this.calendar.render();
```

Comment: maybe you just need to set a flag when the popover is visible, and then, in eventOverlap you check that flag before deciding to show the popover again.

Answer (score 2):

**I had a similar issue** with one project at work.

In my case I have to check if an event (insert by the user with a datepicker component) overlap in the calendar or not.
 So, my idea is to bypass the eventOverlap handler and use the eventDrop handler for call a function that check if the new event overlap or not others.

The function that I used in my case is the one below:

```
// dateStart and dateEnd have to be date strings in ISO format (ex. 1980-10-10)
function isOverlapping(dateStart, dateEnd) {
    var calendarEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

    dateStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dateEnd.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var eventStart;
    var eventEnd;

    for (i in calendarEvents) {
        if (calendarEvents[i].id != 1 && calendarEvents[i].type == undefined) {
            eventStart = new Date(calendarEvents[i].start._d);
            eventStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            eventEnd = new Date(calendarEvents[i].end._d);
            eventEnd.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (eventStart.getTime() < dateEnd.getTime() && eventEnd.getTime() > dateStart.getTime()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With the result of this function you can check if your event overlap others or not, so you can show your confirmation box only if the event overlap and only one time.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope my answer can be useful!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I am still trying to understand the answer. I have one doubt. How will I come to know , which event is static and which event is dragged onto the static event?

Comment: Hi! Sorry if I answer only now. The event dragged is the one in the "info" object (for get it you can simple do "info.event"). The static event is the one that match in the function,  so you can get it doing "return calendarEvents[i]" instead of "return true".

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Issue is , here the id is hardcoded to match id 1 in the if condition. Since my id's can be dynamic, this will not be correct. It can be anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm losing the problem. I thought that the problem was the numerous calls to the overlap handler. Am I wrong? What do you mean with "my id's can be dynamic"?

Comment: Hi Mattia, I have two events on the full-calendar, that are generated from external drag and drop. Hence id of each event can be anything. I need to show a popup, when one event overlaps 2nd event But calendar is generating numerous events

Comment: So, the issue is that the calendar generates more than one event when you do the drag and drop on it? Or the eventOverlap handler does not work properly?

Comment: In case the issue is to find the events dragged (events with a dybamic id) you have to find a way to check if they are dragged or not. Use a flag or some events data

Comment: Hi Mattia, issues if , when one event is overlapped onto the other, fullcalendar, starts calling eventOverlap function, even when the event is not yet dropped . It should have ideally worked like eventDrop. It seems, adding a flag is the only solution. I will try it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome!  Let me know if it works or not. If you continue to don't understand my answer I can make a CodePen for help you.